# SFOAuthCoordinator authenticate issue

Tags: ios

I'm trying to run the code on 64-bit architecture with latest salesforce sdk. But after login it forgets the client_id. Below is the error I got while debugging.

> Assertion failure in -[SFOAuthCoordinator authenticate], /Users/apple/ashu/SalesForce/dev/fpmd-forcepad/Pods/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/libs/SalesforceOAuth/SalesforceOAuth/Classes/SFOAuthCoordinator.m:169
>   2015-10-01 15:36:35.972 Footprints CRM[36766:155035] * WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  credentials.clientId cannot be nil or empty

I had gone through the webview navigation policy but still it shows the same error and that is causing crash in my application.